# Most recently modified record for each user

Tags: python, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'd like to get the most recently modified record for each user in my database specifically using sqlalchemy orm. Here's what I'm trying:

```
session.query(Object)\
       .group_by(Object.user_id)\
       .order_by(Object.updated_at.desc())\
       .first()
```

But getting the following error:

```
(psycopg2.ProgrammingError) column "object.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this error is that you have used `group_by` without an aggregation function.
Try something like this

```
from sqlalchemy import func
session.query(Object.user_id, func.max(Object.updated_at)).group_by(Object.user_id).all()
```

It will return the last `updated_at` value for each user. It makes sense to use `group_by` only if there are several records in the table `Object` with the same `user_id`.

Comment: yes that's a good workaround. but, I want to return the entire last record for each user and not just when that record occurred. would I have to combine queries?

Comment: I see you use postgresql. In postgresql the query `select distinct on (user_id) * from table order by user_id, updated_at desc` should work. In ORM you can try `session.query(Object).distinct(Object.user_id).order_by(Object.user_id, Object.updated_at.desc()).all()`

Comment: @wotalf does it help?

Comment: yup! Works like a charm. I updated your answer to include it